# DB Design: Test Scheduling - Anything Wrong with my Plan?

Tags: sql, database

I am stumped on how to design my database for a test scheduling application I need to design. I will have a testing center. This testing center will have X number of seats. People can schedule a test in 30 min blocks.

At first I was going to populate my DB with records for each available spot, and then mark them as "reserved" but that seems redundant and the wrong way to go about this.

My plan is to have a table (we may have multiple testing centers in the future) that says Testing Center A has X number of seats.

Then when a person attempts to schedule a test (Or when I display avaialble seats) I can query something like this for each 30 min time block:

`SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE startTime == >= x AND endTime <= Y` or something like that. However this would require me to make complex queries everytime I want to know how many seats are open. I'd essentially have to count the number of reservations that exist for each time block, thinking I'd save those start/end times as a span, not just individual records for each 30 min block.

My other plan is like so. If a person reserves a time form 9-10. Create two records, one at 9 and one at 930, but with a foriegn key to an actual reservation record. So to find open seats I could query the table where I am saving the individual blocks reserved.

Has anyone had experience doing a similar application, or advice,examples of where to look to structure this data?w

I know this question is kind of vague, but I don't know where best to post for a discussion. I think there must be a right way to do this to keep normalized data in a simple way. **Is there a better place to ask this?**

Answer (score 0):

you might be better off forgetting about the arbitrary 30 minute blocks and just going with a start and end time.

Comment: I like the start/end time in each reservation record, but doesn't that result in some very messy SQL to find out how many reservations are exist for a given 30 min block?

Comment: @Randy . . . This is appropriate as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I debated that - but since the question is kind of vague, and this is an answer based on the choices given - i moved it here... i wouldn't be upset about moving it back if the question remains unclosed.